# How to colorize Gradle output with sed?

Tags: bash, shell, gradle, sed, colorize

I am trying to process with *sed* the following shell output from *Gradle* to recognize and colorize the severity levels:

```
23:06:28.686 [LIFECYCLE] [system.out] 
23:06:28.686 [QUIET] [system.out] Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'androidx.core.graphics.drawable.IconCompatParcelizer { android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.IconCompat read(androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcel); }', but not the descriptor class 'androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcel'
23:06:28.686 [QUIET] [system.out] Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'androidx.core.graphics.drawable.IconCompatParcelizer { void write(android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.IconCompat,androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcel); }', but not the descriptor class 'androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcel'
23:06:28.710 [QUIET] [system.out] Note: there were 5 references to unknown classes.
23:06:28.711 [QUIET] [system.out]       You should check your configuration for typos.
23:06:28.711 [QUIET] [system.out]       (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unknownclass)
23:06:28.711 [QUIET] [system.out] Note: there were 2 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members.
23:06:28.711 [QUIET] [system.out]       You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes
23:06:28.711 [QUIET] [system.out]       (using '-keep').
23:06:28.711 [QUIET] [system.out]       (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#descriptorclass)
23:06:28.711 [QUIET] [system.out] Note: there were 12 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
23:06:28.711 [QUIET] [system.out]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
23:06:28.711 [QUIET] [system.out]       (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
23:06:28.711 [ERROR] [system.err] Warning: there were 11 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
23:06:28.711 [ERROR] [system.err]          You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
23:06:28.711 [ERROR] [system.err]          If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
23:06:28.711 [ERROR] [system.err]          the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
23:06:28.711 [ERROR] [system.err]          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
23:06:28.711 [QUIET] [system.out] Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
23:06:28.585 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger]
```

I use the following shell script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

c_red=`tput setaf 1`
c_end=`tput sgr0`
./gradlew --info --debug assemble | sed -E -e "s/(\[ERROR\])/${c_red}\1${c_end}/g" \
```

Here is a screenshot of the unprocessed output:

[image: Unprocessed output]

Here is a screenshot of the processed output:

[image: Processed output]

Besides the missing color I noticed that some lines of the output are **lost** in the processed output. Further, Gradle itself seems to **colorize** certain word as one can see in the unprocessed output. The control characters from Gradle and what I use in the *sed* command might **interfere**.

If I choose `LIFECYCLE` instead of `ERROR` then the script works somewhat. Some lines are lost there too! And the Gradle colorization disappears.

[image: Processed output: LIFECYCLE]

I am running this on the Terminal on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: The script you provided works fine with the sample input text for me.

Comment: And if this program is reasonable it should be able to tell it's not outputting to a terminal, so there shouldn't be colour when you're piping it to another process.

Comment: Did you tried [this?](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_customizing_log_format.)

Comment: @LuisMuñoz Interesting. I tried it just now. First I tried `--console=rich` to see the unprocessed output. No new colors, though. Then I added `--console=plain` to my script to omit Gradle colors. No success still :(

Comment: @miken32 I believe the behavior is different because the output from actually running Gradle differs.

Comment: The timestamps are different between the outputs you point out are different so yeah, you're comparing apples and oranges. Run `gradle | tee raw | sed > proc` to get the raw and processed output in different files for the same execution of gradle for comparison.

Comment: Are you referring to the screenshots? If so - then the timestamps differ because I had to run the build multiple times: with and without the script.